clonezilla can't restore image on other device
I have pc1 that run ubuntu 2024 ..I want to get image by clonezilla on flash drive and transfer image to pc2 and run ubuntu like pc1.I have problem with this..pc2 has smaller ssd drive.when I want to transfer image clonezila said and show fault that your current space is small. how can I solve problem ?

Be aware that unless the PC's are identical, drivers may not be compatible. It might be easier to install Ubuntu on the second PC, and then copy files from the first to make them comparable.
